# URxvt - Documentation about keybindings

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, urxvt

Where can I find documentation about how I can change the keybindings for URxvt. Random googling has led me to commands in .Xdefaults such as

```
URxvt.keysym.Meta-k: command:\033]720;1\007
URxvt.keysym.Meta-j: command:\033]721;1\007
```

which maps `k` and `j` to scrolling up or down one step in the terminal. Some experimenting with the commands has led me to think that `\033` (ascii BELL) is used to start the command, `720`/`721` maps to scrolling, `1` is the amount of times the command is repeated and `\007` (ascii ESC) end the command. I have not been able to find information on why just `720` and `721` maps to that or this format is being used.

More specifically, what I am trying to do is to remap `Meta+Shift+k` and `Meta+Shift+j` to scroll through my command history in the terminal, but I have no idea to what number that would correspond to (if it can be done on the same format as described for scrolling).

I have spent several hours in the manpages, but am not able to find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oddly, [urxvt(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/urxvt) "should be" complete, and it points to the "latest version" at http://pod.tst.eu/http://cvs.schmorp.de/rxvt-unicode/doc/rxvt.7.pod but neither contains the relevant text.

For that, it seems you have to read the sources.  In the *manual page* (not the pod-file), you may read

```
   XTerm Operating System Commands
       "ESC ] Ps;Pt ST"
           Set XTerm Parameters. 8-bit ST: 0x9c, 7-bit ST sequence: ESC \
           (0x1b, 0x5c), backwards compatible terminator BEL (0x07) is also
           accepted. any octet can be escaped by prefixing it with SYN (0x16,
           ^V).
```

and

```
           Ps = 720   Move viewing window up by Pt lines, or clear scrollback buffer if Pt = 0 (Compile frills).
           Ps = 721   Move viewing window down by Pt lines, or clear scrollback buffer if Pt = 0 (Compile frills).
```